# Error: failed to fetch from registry: kanso

Tags: node.js, couchdb, npm, kanso

While Im in the process of configuring [Kleks](http://www.markuso.com/essay/project-kleks) i wanted to install [kanso](http://kan.so/) according to [this github article](https://github.com/markuso/kleks).

I successfully installed the `npm` and try to install `kanso` afterword, This is the command that used:

```
stratos@Dev-PC:~$ sudo npm install -g kanso
```

Error log:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kanso

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: kanso
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/stratos/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-26-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "kanso"
npm ERR! cwd /home/stratos
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: kanso
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/stratos/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
stratos@Dev-PC:~$
```

My internet connection is working properly. What is the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the ubuntu version that I used, which is older version of ubuntu 12.04. I ran the same code in ubuntu later version it worked successfully. Since Im using `npm` i have no other choice than upgrading the ubuntu version. Hope [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/) will fix this backward capability issue in there future releases.